# Team Foundation Server Cannot Access Local Shared Drive

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have been experimenting with setting up a continuous-deployment server for a small team using Team Foundation Server. We deploy to a network share, and I have set my publish profile to:
`<publishUrl>\\abcweb1234\dev.general.org$</publishUrl>`
Now when I build in TFS, msbuild is attempting to copy the files to that location, which is perfect, but the agent does not have access.

I have access to the security tab in the NTFS for abcweb1234 and have granted my computer full control. When I look in TFS Express Admin Console, the service account is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. My understanding is that the NETWORK SERVICE account is supposed to present as my computer when accessing the shared drive.

But I have been using ProcMon to inspect, and I can see the user for MsBuild CreateFile is 'NETWORK SERVICE' and the result is access denied. I have also tried granting access Network Service in NTFS but no result.

Am I missing something? Why is Network Service not using my computer name? Do I need to enable a different permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Share permissions needed to be set to read/write. Only NTFS permissions had been set.